# File to import not found or unreadable sass

Tags: css, gulp

I am using gulp to watch for sass from time to time its giving me an error for example " File to import not found or unreadable : 4-layout/header."

Here is my folder structure

[image]

here is how i import header for example inside the main.sass

```
@import '4-layout/header'
```

here is my gulp task

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('source/sass/**/*.sass')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(rename({
            basename: 'main',
            suffix: '.min'
          }))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/css'));
});
```

Comment: Did you miss the underscore at your import? -> 4-layout/_header ?

Comment: Hello michael as far as i know you don't need to put the _  , i also read that on sass documentation

Answer (score 0):

Please try `../4-layout/header` to fix problem.